# use cyrillic non-russian language

Tags: languages

I have a tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{ Українська }
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

It works, but in resulting document (pdf) tableofcontent is called rather by russian word "Содержание" then ukrainian "Зміст". I want ukrainian.
But, when I delete ",russian" from babel package option strange error appears:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option russian yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \select@language{russian}
```

How to fix this?
Is there other ways to use ukrainian language as default?

Comment: I think you gave up too early. Try another TeX run.

Comment: I tried 10 runs....

Comment: But when I delete all temporary files... It works! Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't stop a run with `x`. In that case the `.aux` file doesn't get overwritten. But deleting the `.aux` file was just what was needed. Congrats!

Comment: The language declared last with `babel` is the default one. So, if you need both Russian and Ukrainian, the latter being the main one, write `\usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel}`. If you can, switch to UTF-8 encoding, rather than `cp1251`.

Comment: As it actually works, I closed the question.